# Setting syntax Perl in Gvim

Tags: syntax, vim

How can I automatically set the syntax of a certain file extension same as that of an existing language(say Perl) in Gvim ?

Comment: How and Why ? Is it important ?

Comment: It'll highlight a correct answer, and that you respect people's efforts in answering your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl  setf perl
```

This tells vim that any file ending in `.pl` should be treated as perl (`setf perl` sets the filetype).

Comment: Where should I put my file extension which need to be mapped to Perl ?